# GET parameters validation

Tags: yii2

Every Yii2 guide/tutorial that I have come across ignores the validation of GET parameters. I'm wondering why.

To give an example, take a look at this code:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    /* @var $model ActiveRecord */
    $model = Model::findOne($id);

    if ($model) {
        return $this->render('view', ['model' => $model]);
    } else {
        throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException();
    }
}
```

I understand that if you pass invalid argument to `findOne()` method, it will just return `null` and nothing bad happens. But is this really the best practice? I have always tried to be very careful with user input and the way I see it, user input should be validated immediately before performing any operations such as DB calls. Even if it's GET data, not just POST data.

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    /* @var $model yii\base\DynamicModel */
    $model = DynamicModel::validateData(['id' => $id], [
        'idValidation' => ['id', integer]
    ]);

    if ($model->hasErrors()) {
        throw new \yii\web\BadRequestHttpException();
    }

    /* @var $model yii\db\ActiveRecord */
    $model = Model::findOne($id);

    if ($model) {
        return $this->render('view', ['model' => $model]);
    } else {
        throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException();
    }
}
```

What do you think? Is my approach reasonable or overkill and unnecessary?

Comment: Well you are not inserting anything to the database with GET and only search for the `primary_key` or `column=>value` combination when using `findOne()`, and by default Gii generates code with `NotFoundException` when there is nothing matching the condition or key or `findOne()` returns `null` , i think its overkill to validate a parameter that is used for searching the table, other than you are using the search model to filter out records, you can use the default validation rules in the `searchModel`. Maybe someone else can explain it better, or correct if i am wrong here

Comment: I understand that `findOne()` will return `null` when it doesn't find any results. This was actually mentioned in the post as well. I want to emphasize that it shouldn't matter what you do in your controller - what should matter is that all user input is always validated regardless of how the data is being used. I think it's very dangerous to assume that you can safely ignore some user input.

Comment: as i said when using forms for user inputs you use searchModel and all your inputs are validated according to defined rules.

Comment: I am aware of the way search model handles validation. This is great but I still want an answer to my original question.
Should we not validate **everything** without exceptions? I find it very odd that we just ignore validation for simple actions because for example, `findOne` doesn't care what value you pass to it.
Edit: I made a mistake in my original post claiming that every tutorial ignores GET validation. Indeed, there are tutorials and examples of search models that handle validation perfectly, but the simplier most basic examples completely ignore any validation.

Comment: i think the answer below has explained it why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using action parameters, you don't need to validate this parameters again (unless you have specific reason for it, like closed dictionary of allowed values, but I guess this is not the case). If your action uses signature like `actionView($id)` Yii will ensure few things before further processing of action:

1. `$_GET['id']` exist, so `$id` will never be `null`. If someone will try to call this action without `id` value in GET, he will get `BadRequestHttpException` exception without calling action.
2. `$_GET['id']` is a scalar. It means that if someone will try to pass array as `id`, he will get `BadRequestHttpException` exception without calling action.

So at this point in action you may be sure that `$id` is string. This is enough for `findOne()` safety. Even if you expect integer and someone pass `blablabla` as `$id`, it does not matter - he will get `NotFoundHttpException` anyway since there is no record with `blablabla` as `id` (this is impossible - `blablabla` in not a valid integer) - there is no need for extra check here. So default examples generated by Gii or from Yii documentation are safe. So your approach is a overkill and it is completely unnecessary.

---

Situation may change when `$id` can be array, since array allows much more powerful syntax. You need to take extra attention when:

1. You're explicitly allowing array as action param: `actionView(array $id)`.
2. You're not using action params and using `$_GET` params directly: `$id = $_GET['id']` or `$id = Yii::$app->request->get('id')` - in these cases `$id` can be array even if you're expecting scalar.

In this case `$id` value may be quite surprising. For example attacker may pass multiple IDs even if you're expecting single ID. Or filter by specified field instead of primary key, by passing `['email' => 'user@example.com']` as a `$id` - users will be searched by `email` field (or any other) even if intention is to filter only by ID. In such cases you should validate this array to make sure that it contains only expected values.

In older version this also allows for SQL Injection, since columns names (keys in array) were not escaped (this is still valid for `where()`). See [2.0.15 release announcement](https://www.yiiframework.com/news/168/releasing-yii-2-0-15-and-database-extensions-with-security-fixes#not-affected-code) with some explanation.